# How to convert a docx to pdf in flask

Tags: python, flask, format-conversion

So i am making a flask web app and i added a docx to pdf converter but its not working every time i will ran into a problem even though it is simple so i am using this python package to convert docx to pdf https://pypi.org/project/docx2pdf/ and i made it till where i upload files in flask and it start converting. I get error when converting it

this is my code

```
@app.route("/pdf", methods=["POST"])
def pdf2docx_post():
    file = request.files['file']

    if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
        filename = file.filename
        file.save(secure_filename(filename))
        convert(filename, filename.split('.')[0] + '.docx')
        
        convert(filename, "output.pdf")
        convert(filename)
        return send_file("output.pdf", as_attachment=True)


        return render_template("pdf.html", wait="Pleas wait your download will start automatically")
```

i get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\UwU\OneDrive\Desktop\UwU web\Web Development\all-in-one-tools\tools-web\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2091, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\UwU\OneDrive\Desktop\UwU web\Web Development\all-in-one-tools\tools-web\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2076, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\UwU\OneDrive\Desktop\UwU web\Web Development\all-in-one-tools\tools-web\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\UwU\OneDrive\Desktop\UwU web\Web Development\all-in-one-tools\tools-web\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\UwU\OneDrive\Desktop\UwU web\Web Development\all-in-one-tools\tools-web\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\UwU\OneDrive\Desktop\UwU web\Web Development\all-in-one-tools\tools-web\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1502, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\UwU\OneDrive\Desktop\UwU web\Web Development\all-in-one-tools\app\main.py", line 145, in pdf2docx_post
    convert(filename, filename.split('.')[0] + '.docx')
  File "C:\Users\UwU\OneDrive\Desktop\UwU web\Web Development\all-in-one-tools\tools-web\Lib\site-packages\docx2pdf\__init__.py", line 102, in convert
    paths = resolve_paths(input_path, output_path)
  File "C:\Users\UwU\OneDrive\Desktop\UwU web\Web Development\all-in-one-tools\tools-web\Lib\site-packages\docx2pdf\__init__.py", line 94, in resolve_paths
    assert str(output_path).endswith(".pdf")
AssertionError
```

Thanks in advance

**NOTE: I ALREADY USED MANY STACKOVERFLOW ANSWERS BUT IT DIDNT WORKED**

Answer (score 1):

You can do this..it will work.I struggled with this `CoInitialize has not been called error` too and it will work in your case too..

```
from docx2pdf import convert  
import os   
import pythoncom
```

```
convert(your_input_filepath, your_output_directory_path, pythoncom.CoInitialize())
```

For the `your_input_filepath` , `your_output_directory_path` you can give relative input path and output path using `os.path.relpath("put_your_filepath_here")`

Answer (score 0):

From the error it seems the function expects the filename to end with `".pdf"` so you could remove these two extra lines:

```
convert(filename, filename.split('.')[0] + '.docx')       
convert(filename)
```

and leave

```
convert(filename, "output.pdf")
```

Comment: nope not working getting this error `pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221008, 'CoInitialize has not been called.', None, None)`